# change the order off divs with same name using jquery

Tags: jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/psh23k7v/

```
  <span id="a">First </span>
  <span class="number">1</span>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span id="b">Second </span>
  <span class="number">1</span>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span id="c">Third </span>
  <span class="number">1</span>
</div>

<div>
<a id="knop">change</a>
</div>
```

```
$("#knop").click(function(){   

var aaa = $('.wrapper #a');
var bbb = $('.wrapper #b');
var ccc = $('.wrapper #c');

bbb.insertBefore(aaa);


});
```

this way the span moves the first wrapper . but i want the whole second wrapper to move to the top (or another place (imagine 20 wrappers and you want the 9th to move to the second place)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to move the second wrapper to the top.

```
let first_wrapper = $('.wrapper:first-child');
let second_wrapper = $('.wrapper:nth-child(2)'); // you can change 2 into other number
second_wrapper.insertBefore(first_wrapper);
```

Comment: yes, that does work. but the wrapper is a commonly used class on the page so that is why i want to use the span id beacause it is unique

Comment: Then you can use jquery closest method that can search for the closest parent of the element, like $('#a').closest('.wrapper'), or $('#b').closest('.wrapper').

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
$("#knop").click(function() {

  var aaa = $('.wrapper #a');
  var bbb = $('#b').parent('.wrapper');
  var ccc = $('.wrapper #c');

  bbb.insertBefore(aaa);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span id="a">First </span>
  <span class="number">1</span>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span id="b">Second </span>
  <span class="number">1</span>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span id="c">Third </span>
  <span class="number">1</span>
</div>

<div>
<a id="knop">change</a>
</div>
```